# Sliding menu toggle option

Tags: android, menu, slidingmenu

I want to use the menu button on  android to make the sliding menu toggle from left to right. The problem I face is that since I have used the sliding menu functionality in my main activity on create method, I do not how to use the same variable in the onPrepareOptionMenu method.

```
SlidingMenu menu;
    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    menu.setShadowWidth(10);
    menu.setBehindOffset(60);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.25f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
    menu.setBehindWidth(400);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
```

this is the code which I use to call the sliding menu, However, I want to enable the toggle button whenever the menu button is called along side the swipe gesture .

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    //try to enable the toggle here so that the sliding menu can appear/disappear
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that unlike most cases, I do not extend my main class with the Sherlock activity since my main class is already extending some other activity. Hence I use the sliding menu in form of a constructor(look at my example). I am not sure how to integrate the toggle function. Thank for all the help

Comment: post the menu_frame xml and activity_main xml codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need override OptionsMenu methods and you want this methods public your Activity, then you first create Activity to Options menu and in you activity need extends CustomOptionMenuActivity.
Example:
1. Create CustomOptionMenuActivity:

```
public class CustomOptionMenuActivity extends Activity {
    private Menu SlidingMenu;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.SlidingMenu = menu;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
       //try to enable the toggle here so that the sliding menu can appear/disappear
       return true;
    }
}
```

Then you can use menu in any activities, but you need extends this activity. 
Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends CustomOptionMenuActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Good luck!